# How to check if a large python pandas data frame has duplicates (do not need the actual duplicate rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  3000+ csv files with each file about 30 MB. I just need to check if any of these files have duplicates. I don't need to actually which rows are duplicates. So if there is even one row that has been found to be a duplicate, then we do not need to check for other rows that are duplicate and we can stop the scanning of the file there and move onto the next file. 
the pandas function

```
.duplicate
.duplicated
```

are not useful as they will scan the entire dataframe. They will not stop on finding the first duplicate.
Is there any other function that will just quickly allow to check if a dataframe(from a csv file) has duplicates or not
Thanks for any inputs

Comment: Is there a specific column in those files you need to check if duplicates exist?

Comment: iterate over the enumerated rows, adding each row to a `set`, and check if the length of the set is less than the current iteration index, if it is, a duplicate was found.

Comment: I don't quite understand the desired output. Do you need a single truth value (True/False) if any two rows are duplicated anywhere in the 3000+ csv files? Or for each file do you need to know if a duplicate row exists somewhere in another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iterate over the enumerated rows, adding each row to a set, and check if the length of the set is less than the current iteration index plus one, if it is, a duplicate was found.

```
s = set()
for ix, row in enumerate(rows):
  s.add(row)
  if len(s) < (ix + 1):
    break  # duplicate found!
    # or: 
    # raise Exception("Duplicate found!")
```

Comment: In terms of both time and space, it is `O(n)` for a file with no dupes, `O(k)` for a file with dupes where `k` is the position of the first dupe in the entire collection of rows. Adding and checking the set is O(1) on average.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would try -

```
from subprocess import check_output
from glob import glob

files = glob("*.csv")
for file in files:
    x = check_output(f"sort {file} | uniq -d", shell=True)
    if len(x) > 0:
        print(file)
```

This would print out all the files which contain duplicates. I could check it for txt files, hence hoping that it should work for CSV's too.

The advantage being that you don't have to load the csvs as dataframes, hence should be faster than other approaches. Note that I'm using `f-string` which works only in python3.7 or above. So, modify it otherwise to use `format`

Please, try it out & let me know if it works for you.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: `subprocess.check_output => check_output` also the print() is indented a little too far

Comment: This isa good idea... and it worked on a small subset. But it appears to be taking a larger time as compared to the first approach. I am not sure why. It also actually depends on the data. Unfortunately there is no way for me to Mark 2 answers as possible good so I am marking only the answer which is working for me right now. But this is good and thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated will return a boolean for all of the rows if they are duplicates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1],
                   [1,1,2,1],
                   [2,2,2,2],
                   [2,2,2,2]])


print(df.duplicated().any())
>>> True
```